# GCP VM instance was not accessible

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

One of the VM instance's network went down i.e it was neither accessible via ssh nor it could communicate with other machine in LAN.

Access was restored when the instance was restarted.

This log was found in syslog
" Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP."

Need to know why this happen and workaround to prevent it in future

Edit:
Issue is Communication with the VM Instance was down. It was not accessible nor it could communicate with other machines.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that system had the old config in the place.

> The symlink `/etc/resolv.conf` pointed to `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`

Changing it to point to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` which is managed by systemd.

Comment: What was the issue actually?  Without changing symlink, it works after restart.

Comment: How come VM was not accessible via SSH

Comment: This warning is logged by systemd-resolved, whenever a name can not be resolved by the DNS system (e.g. nslookup www.domain.com). This can be tolerated and is no reason to be alarmed.

Comment: Actually it's a issue for us.  Communication is stopped completely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with a similar issue (server inaccessible, even by ssh). In my case, the `NXDOMAIN` log looks to be a red herring.

I/O utilization spikes massively before an outage, similar to https://serverfault.com/a/933194/523972: [image]